# Show $\sum_{k = 0}^{\infty} \frac{z^{4k}}{(4k)!} - \frac{z^{4k + 2}}{(4k + 2)!} = \sum_{k = 0}^{\infty} (-1)^k \frac{z^{2k}}{(2k)!}$

Tags: real-analysis

Please explain the steps for going from the LHS to RHS
$$
2\sum\limits_{k = 0}^\infty  {\left( {{{{z^{4k}}} \over {\left( {4k} \right)!}} - {{{z^{\left( {4k + 2} \right)}} \over {\left( {4k + 2} \right)!}}}} \right)}
= 2\sum\limits_{k = 0}^\infty  {{{\left( { - 1} \right)}^k}{{{z^{2k}}} \over {\left( {2k} \right)!}}}
$$

Comment: Start by expressing the second part of the LHS in terms of the first part of the LHS?

Comment: Perhaps use a different index for the series on the right, there is a factor 2 between the $k$ on the left and right. Note that $(-1)^{2k}=1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint for intuition**
$$
\sum_{k = 0}^{\infty} \left( \frac{z^{4k}}{(4k)!} - \frac{z^{4k + 2}}{(4k + 2)!}\right)
= \left(\frac{z^0}{0!} - \frac{z^2}{2!}\right) + \left( \frac{z^4}{4!} - \frac{z^6}{6!}\right) + \left( \frac{z^8}{8!} - \frac{z^{10}}{10!}\right) + \ldots
$$
Do you see the pattern?

Rather than believing that the first few terms match you can think of it like this:

Let $x_n := \frac{z^n}{n!}$.
In the LHS every $4$-th index and every $(4k + 2)$-th index of the sequence $x_n$ are used. This means every second index used since $4k + 2 + 2 = 4(k + 1)$. Every second of those terms is subtract every other added. Therefore, their sign alternates.

Comment: Do you mean 4k-th index of $ \{x_n\}  $?

Comment: @Megamatics Basically. I didn't know how to write it down unmistakably. You take every $4$-th index of $x_n$ and every second after every $4$-th index. So, the $4k$-th and $(4k + 2)$-th index for every $k$.